# Asignar DateTime a input type=datetime-local con :value

Tags: laravel, vue.js

estoy intentando asignar a un input tipo datetime-local fechas que me devuelve el servidor pero no asigna, he intentado con :value, v-bind y v-model, tambien formateando la fecha con moment.js pero sigo sin conseguir nada.

este es mi codigo:

cronograma.vue

template

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Etapa</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha Hora Inicio</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha Hora Fin</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(actividad, index) in actividades" :key="actividad.idConvocatoriaCronograma">
                    <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
                    <td class="text-left">{{ actividad.etapa.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group mb--2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Seleccione fecha" type="datetime-local" :value="formatearFecha(actividad.fechai)"  required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group mb--2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select date" type="datetime-local" :value="formatearFecha(actividad.fechaf)"  required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

script

```
export default {
props: [ 'idconvocatoria' ],
created() {
    this.getCronograma();
},
data: function () {
    return {
        actividades: [],
    }
},
methods: {
    getCronograma: function () {
        let url = '/intranet/convocatorias/getetapas/'+this.idconvocatoria;
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.actividades = response.data;
        }).catch(error => {
            toastr.error('no se pudo traer el cronograma');
        });
    },
    formatearFecha: function (date) {
        return moment(date).format();
    }
}
```

}

resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al ejemplo que ofreces `2019-02-15 07:00:00` el formato no será reconocido.

Debe ser una fecha completa valida de acuerdo a la especificación  [rfc3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339). En resumen debe cumplir estas condiciones en este mismo orden:

1. una fecha
2. la letra "T"
3. una hora

Por ejemplo:

```
1985-04-12T23:20:50.52
1996-12-19T16:39:57
```

Ejemplo de un `input` tipo `datetime-local`:

```
<label for="party">Enter a date and time for your party booking:</label>
<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate" value="2017-06-01T08:30">
```

Comment: pero el formatearFecha() mediante moment.js hace esa conversion, retorna y resien es asignado (en teoria). formatearFecha('2019-02-15 07:00:00'){ return '2019-02-15T07:00:00'}

Comment: Si formateas `moment("2019-02-15 07:00:00").format()` obtienes `"2019-02-15T07:00:00-05:00"` el cual sigue siendo un formato incorrecto para ese input